# Service Account working on local machine but not on Web server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web application that authenticates its users through a Service Account. It works perfectly on my local machine allowing the ones that are in there and keeping the unauthorized away. However, when I upload into a web server it does not recognize the SA at all. Any idea why? Here's what I got:

```
System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
string securityGroup = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("AUTHORIZED_USERS", "AUTHORIZED_ADMIN".GetType());

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal user = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(identity);
//if user cannot access, notify them and close application
if (!user.IsInRole(securityGroup))
{
    Response.Redirect("Unauthorized.aspx");
    return;
}
```

Config:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="AUTHORIZED_USERS" value="CORP.ACME.COM\AUTHORIZED_USER"/>
    <add key="AUTHORIZED_ADMIN" value="CORP.ACME.COM\AUTHORIZED_Admin"/>
  </appSettings>

<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

IIS on the web server is setup with the credentials and password for the service account under the Identity in the pool that I specifically have setup for this application but it is not recognizing it and never passes the authentication process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with, runs locally? On a local IIS, or are you using the developer iis express. The last one, started by visual studio are configured for windows authentication. When you deploy to IIS, you need the same settings

Answer (score 0):

Check if you enabled windows authentication,impersonation and remaining to false for your application.
 iis -> click on your application -> select authentication from the panel.